# Geolocation permission for subdomain

Tags: javascript, geolocation, subdomain

I need geolocation on my site for login and for a few other operations throughout my site.  For security reasons we have our login server on its own server under its own domain, i.e. `login.com`, and our site `site.com`.  Currently the user is prompted to allow location on both, which is less than desirable. Will putting the login server as a subdomain, `login.site.com`, allow the user to grant permission only once?

Comment: Sub-domains should be fine. I would've expected you to have more trouble with session cookies in different domains?

Comment: not using session cookies.  Oauth2 and localstorage

Comment: Same comment for localStorage. I use Oauth2 Google and Facebook and don't need your architecture.